# Can't configure font in Tkinter (anaconda)

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, anaconda

I have Tkinter ver. 8.5 from anaconda. No matter what I do (and I have tried everything on stackoverflow, google and several tutorials), I cant change the font of any text element. I am mostly trying it with labels but nothing seems to work. How can I debug this? Are there any known issues for the configuration I just mentioned (Centos VM on Windows 7 machine running anaconda instead of python)?

```
label = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr, font="Helvetica 16 bold italic")
label = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr, font=("Helvetica", 16))
label.config(font=("Courier", 44))
```

**EDIT:** I'm on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Does Anaconda have it's own labels. I used to use Anaconda about a year ago and can't remember any differences from regular Python/Tkinter except for the additional packages.

I tried to run the examples above in Python 3.6.5 under Win10 and all of them works just fine. Maybe its somtehing else in your code..., try running the example code below standalone and you will know if it's anaconda or your code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
timestr = StringVar()
timestr.set('Parrot')
label = Label(root, textvariable=timestr, font="Helvetica 16 bold italic")
label.pack()
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention...I am on python 2.7

Comment: Well, since you're running Tkinter 8.5 it should really be enough to import from `Tkinter` (with capital T) instead. If this doesn't work I'm out of ideas.